# How can I delete an element from a JSON file using javascript

Tags: javascript, json

`var obj= {"table":[{"id":1},{"id":2}]}`

For example I want to delete the entire element where the id==2.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: FWIW, this isn't JSON, but a Javascript Object. JSON is a string.

Answer (score 2):

SIMPLY with [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```js
var obj= {"table":[{"id":1},{"id":2}]}
const objFiltered = obj["table"].filter(({id})=>id!==2)
obj["table"] = objFiltered;
console.log(obj)
```